# How to update a time-series model (such as facebook_prophet) on new data without retraining the data in full each time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, regression, facebook-prophet

Is it doable to update my trained model (fbprophet) in order to surpass the dilemma of retraining the whole dataset every time?

Thanks for your help in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the warm-start approach, [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/46#issuecomment-513371634).